# HDD does not mount when restarting

Tags: mount, external-hdd, hard-drive, restart

I have two external HDD attached to my PC which start normally when I turn on the PC. When I restart (after an update for example) one of the two drives does not mount, always the same drive. It has always acted like this but I was wondering was there a way to fix this.

Currently running Ubuntu 10.10, let me know if more information would help

Comment: Please post an output of your fstab file: cat /etc/ftab

Comment: They mount automatically or you added them manually to `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: I have never needed to mount manually, just plugged them into the PC

Comment: This is my /etc/fstab

Comment: # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#

Comment: # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=5137d402-5faa-4f27-be74-63aa41e82372 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=84317423-3293-4868-beac-8198297a1fbf /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=0f5b11d6-55ae-43b8-ad2a-e1cd5f41852d none            swap    sw              0       0

Answer (score 1):

Add the disk to the fstab configuration file.

Check following page:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/fstab

Comment: Thanks for that but when I tried adding both drives disappeared at start-up and half of docky disappeared for some reason. Undid the changes and everything back to normal. Have tried a few variations of the command line but no joy, really a novice with that end of things. The 2nd HDD is not listed in Fstab but it mounts and runs fine when I restart, but adding the other HDD gets rid of both! Will keep poking around

Comment: OK, looks like I broke something now I can not even mount the drive: "Error mounting: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdg1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so"

Comment: I think I have fixed everything now. Added both drives and all the errors have gone away. But when I restart I get a message on the screen saying the 'problem' drive is not yet ready or mounted and to either to skip or mount manually. I skipped. Shutdown, started up and logged in fine. So the restart process is still throwing up issues

Comment: link it broken.